# _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "sample.gif": no such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

There's a really weird problem with tkinter.

I can usually show the images on tkinter.
But, I can not show any images on it if I try to load music files.

For example,

```
import tkinter as Tk

class Frame(Tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
    Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


    self.f = Tk.Frame(self)
    self.f.pack()

    self.ARTWORK = ['guthrie.gif']

    self.f_artwork = Tk.Frame(self.f)
    self.f_artwork.pack()
    self.artwork_img = Tk.PhotoImage(file=self.ARTWORK[0])

    self.artwork_la = Tk.Label(self.f_artwork, image=self.artwork_img)
    self.artwork_la.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':

f = Frame()
f.pack()
f.mainloop()
```

I can show the image in this case, but

```
import tkinter as Tk
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import pygame

song_list = []

directory = askdirectory()
os.chdir(directory)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        realdir = os.path.realpath(file)
        song_list.append(file)

    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(song_list[0])
    pygame.mixer.music.play()




pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(song_list[0])
pygame.mixer.music.play()

class Frame(Tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, master=None):
    Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


    self.f = Tk.Frame(self)
    self.f.pack()

    self.ARTWORK = ['guthrie.gif']

    self.f_artwork = Tk.Frame(self.f)
    self.f_artwork.pack()
    self.artwork_img = Tk.PhotoImage(file=self.ARTWORK[0])

    self.artwork_la = Tk.Label(self.f_artwork, image=self.artwork_img)
    self.artwork_la.pack()

if __name__ == '__maim__':

f = Frame()
f.pack()
f.mainloop()
```

For this program, I cannot show the image on Tkinter.
Tkinter cannot recongnize the file.
Error message is 
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "guthrie.gif": no such file or directory

Can you tell me what the cause is?

Comment: Well, how were you expecting it to still find guthrie.gif after you've explicitly changed to a different directory?  That `os.chdir()` seems unnecessary (you can list the directory without it being your current directory) - if it must stay for some reason, then either load the image first, change back to the original directory, or use an absolute pathname for the image file.

Comment: @jasonharper Why isn't this an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running `os.chdir(directory)`, you changed the directory from where the script was ran. If you want to keep the old functionality you can capture and save the script directroy with `os.getcwd()`. Try something like this.

```
import tkinter as Tk
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import pygame

song_list = []

scriptDir = os.getcwd()  # directory from where script was ran
directory = askdirectory()
os.chdir(directory)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        realdir = os.path.realpath(file)
        song_list.append(file)

...

class Frame(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)


        self.f = Tk.Frame(self)
        self.f.pack()
        os.chdir(scriptDir)  # change to the starting directory
        self.ARTWORK = ['guthrie.gif']

        ...
```